# Android textview is not showing up in relative layout.

Tags: android, textview

I am having a bit of trouble with android relative layout. I want the textview with the text "Maze" to appear in the center of two buttons: quit and play. However, the text is not appearing.

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="ui.AMazeActivity" >
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#333333"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/play"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/quit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/quit_button_text"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/play"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/play_button_text"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/quit"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/play"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/quit"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/quit"
        android:text="@string/maze_textview_text"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the picture: (Note that Maze text should appear in between quit and play)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/play"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/quit"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/quit"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/quit"
    android:text="@string/maze_textview_text"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize it was such a small error. I thought it had something to do with layer visibility.

Comment: @Renren29 have u check my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Use this.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="ui.AMazeActivity" >

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/play"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#333333" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/quit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="quit"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/play"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="play"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/play"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/play"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Maze"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="17sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

For this widget alone, you should use a LinearLayout with it's orientation set to Horizontal.

I will write you a bit of code ,just to get you started, but I really don't wanna spend my time writing everything as it should be be.Anyways, I am sure you will figure it out right away.

```
<LinearLayout
  android:orientation="horizontal">
  <!-- And whatever other stuff you have to set,like width ,height,bla bla -->
  <Button></Button>  <!-- This is the Quit button-->   
  <TextView></TextView>  <!-- This is the TextView that shows "Maze"--> 
  <Button></Button>  <!-- This is the Play button-->
</LinearLayout>
```

So, all in all, by using the LinearLayout with orientation set horizontal, every element you add in the layout, will be put to the right of the element added before.The first element, get's added in the left-top corner of the layout.

If you need more information, let me know via comment and I will help you up.